# Interpreting as unsigned 32 bit integer with PHP

Tags: php, integer, unsigned

I am trying to make little PHP tool for World of Tanks that will read battle replays.
You can see [there](http://wiki.vbaddict.net/pages/File_Replays) what each replay consists of and [there](http://herhor.tk/wot/steppes.txt) is an example.

Unfortunately I don't understand this part of wiki article:

> Read 4 bytes, and interpret these as an unsigned 32 bit integer, let this be "block count"

I tried to convert their Java code to PHP, but it outputs "0" all the time.
Also I tried code found at php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#38478 but it outputs "0" too.

Here is my current code:

```
function parse($string)
{
$x = (float)$string;
if ($x > (float)2147483647)
$x -= (float)"4294967296";
return (int)$x;
}

$replay = file_get_contents('steppes.txt');

$magic = substr($replay, 0, 4);
$count = substr($replay, 4, 4);

echo $magic." -- ".parse($magic)."<br>".$count." -- ".parse($count);
```

Comment: Can you show the example what you did?

Comment: @StuiterSlurf sure, added to question. Result you can check there: http://herhor.tk/wot/replay.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the PHP-function [unpack](http://php.net/unpack) to convert binary data.

In your case you should use the code `V` which is for

> unsigned long (always 32 bit, little endian byte order)

(long is a name used for a 32bit integer). You didn't specify the used byte-order, but looking at your demo-data I assume it is little endian. For a list of all 'codes', see the documentation of the [pack-function](http://php.net/pack).

```
$replay = file_get_contents('steppes.txt');
$info = unpack('Vmagic/Vcount', $replay);
echo 'Magic: ' . $info['magic'];
echo '<br/>';
echo 'Count: ' . $info['count'];
```

Comment: Unpack does the same thing as your `parse` (should) do. The 'V' is to tell him what type of conversion should be done. `unpack('V', substr($replay, 4, 4))` gives a simular result (try it) and looks more like your original code. The beauty of this function is that you can read multiple values at once (seperated by `/`) so you don't need all the `substr`

Comment: Ok, thanks. If I want to pack it back, will pack('V', $count); work?

Comment: Yep, exactly. Or `pack('VV', $magic, $count)` to pack both. Double 'V' for two integers, followed by the values.

Comment: One more question, can I use `$count = unpack('V', substr($replay, 4, 4))[1];` to avoid using `$count[1]` everywhere?

Comment: Yes you can (as of PHP 5.4)